# Can I use one primer/sealer on new drywall & existing painted surfaces?

Tags: drywall, paint, priming

It's nearing time to paint a newly converted laundry/storage room, and I'm trying to determine if I can get away with a single primer/sealer or if I would have better luck with a couple of more targeted options based on what I'm working with:

- Two full walls of new drywall, level 4
- A few moderately sized drywall patches (12 - 16 sq. ft. each) in existing walls and ceiling
- Existing wall paint: Behr Ultra Scuff Defense - Eggshell Enamel, Polar White
- Existing ceiling paint: Behr Ultra Scuff Defense - Extra Durable Flat
- Existing walls, ceiling to be repainted
- Airless sprayer application

Based on some research, my initial thought was just to run with Bulls Eye 1-2-3 for all surfaces but I'm now thinking it may be a good idea to use a high build primer/sealer on the new drywall and then use the 1-2-3 on the patches and existing painted surfaces. Based on local availability, I'm considering PPG SPEEDHIDE MaxPrime for the drywall primer/sealer.

Any thoughts/recommendations on how to best proceed?

Comment: I usually like the KISS idea.  Prep of the surfaces is usually more important than what you slap on to them.

Comment: Agreed. It's probably going to depend on how well you give the existing paint a key for the new paint to adhere to. You may not even need primer on the existing paint unless you're changing from a darker to lighter color.

Comment: If the old paint was oil based and the new is water based, or vice versa, you may want a primer between them that will stick strongly to both. Historically that has meant a shellac/alcohol-based primer; there may be modern "universal" alternatives. This is more often a problem for clear costs, but I'd worry a bit about paint too. If in doubt, universal primer won't make things worse.

Comment: high build primer? "It is a primer that combines skim coating and priming steps into one spray application over properly prepared new drywall." - skim coating isn't primer's job. It's adhesion to the substrate, and *it* becoming a suitable one. Should be the lightest coat you can achieve but still have full coverage (and not necessarily opaque by any means whatsoever). - Can't recommend anything w/o the finish paint telling me what a suitable substrate is. For F&B, that'd be F&B's (interior) Wall & Ceiling Primer. It's also $300 a gallon....